# Chrome Developer Tools: Break Points Inconsistently Stopping When They Should

Tags: javascript, debugging, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, webpack

I've been using breakpoints points in the dev tools for a hot minute

but...

**recently Chrome Developer Tools Break Points just don't stop on lines of codes that 100% it should of stopped on.(it's become ambiguously  inconsistent).**

Sometimes I will have to exit out of the tab or refresh multiple times to get it to hit the break point finally.

---

**Question
Are there common reasons why Chrome dev tool break points can become inconsistent like this?**

---

Just in case it matters:

Setup - Reactjs 0.14.0, Webpack Bundling, Linux

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./js/app.js",
  output: {
    filename: "js/bundle.js"
  },
  debug: true,
  devtool: "#eval-source-map",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: So far I found changing "devtool "  to "source-map" is really helping. I'll keep you guys posted if that is the final answer! :)

Comment: The ways I can think of this happening are 1. an infinite loop or 2. an asynchronous call that doesn't return or timeout.  Do you have either of these in your code?  What happens if you put breakpoints at intermediate steps in the code, do they get hit?  Can you identify the code block where this happens?